# Strange behavior doing a Where against IDocumentSession.Query<MyClass>

Tags: ravendb

**1.**

```
documentSession.Query<MyClass>
               .Where(my=>lastNames.Any(my.FullName.EndsWith))
               .ToList();
```

**2.**

```
Func<MyClass,bool> filter = myClass=>lastNames.Any(myClass.FullName.EndsWith);

documentSession.Query<MyClass>.Where(filter).ToList();
```

First one will result in an exception. Second one will return results.

Am I missing something? Or I just don't understand the internal expression tree builder algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

- Don't use `EndsWith` in a RavenDB query.  It's too slow.  Instead, create a static index with the reversed form of the string, and then using `StartsWith` in your queries.  [Read here for details.](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ravendb/j0b5FVs_IGc/tOb_tU_IqM8J)
- You might want to do a [Search](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/client-api/querying/static-indexes/searching) instead, using a custom [Analyzer](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/appendixes/lucene-indexes-usage).
- The difference between the two code examples is that the first passes a type of `Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>>` while the second passes `Func<MyClass, bool>`.  Because it's not an expression, it doesn't translate to the query.  Instead, you are querying the server without any fitler.  After all results are returned, then the filter is being applied *client-side*.

Comment: they both compile. EndsWith is passed as a delegate to the Any function. I understand the query doesn't have the performance there. However, I am more concerned why #1 will give an exception at runtime while #2 works fine. To me, they look like they are doing the same thing.

Comment: Oh, I see.  You are essentially saying "where `FullName` ends with any of the values in the `lastNames` list".  Right?